# What is the difference between "=" (equality sign) and "of" in *ngFor in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I happened to make a copy-pasty mistake when creating iterators with indexes as shown below.

```
<beep *ngFor="let thing of stuff; let i of index;">...</beep>
```

The correct version is supposed to contain equality sign instead of *of* in the index statement. **The question is not about how to get index.**

What interests me is that I got *[Object object]* and I wonder what that object is. Normally, I'd just print it to the console but I can't access the console from the template markup. Also, googling for *difference = of angular* disregards the equality sign and gives me differences between *ngFor* and **ngFor*, as well as a bunch of other directives. Not sure if it's possible to google for sign operators at all (and  quick googling for that seems to [confirm my suspicion](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)).

What is the object that *index* provides?

Comment: you could console your object in template using `json`  pipe

Comment: Relevant section of the docs: https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#microsyntax. Structural directives (the ones that begin with `*`) are a lot more complex than they might appear at first glance, and I'd recommend reading that whole page if you want to learn more about how they work :)

Comment: Due to how structural directives are desugared to regular directives, I'd expect that i === thing in your case. `let i of index` is just a mistake and I'm surprised that it works at all. Don't do this and use `let i = index` instead. As it was mentioned above, you can use json pipe to output object contents to the tempalte.

Comment: @estus Glad to have found a surprise for you. I try to do things thoroughly and do every mistake at least once, hehe. Feel free to verify that you get the same result as I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be exactly the same object as `thing` in your case.